# Accessing the Layer Panel in After Effects

Tags: after-effects

I want to edit the anchor point path of a layer, and to do that I know I need to open the layer in it's own layer panel. However I can't figure out how to open the layer in the layer panel.

I'm following along with a beginner tutorial, and using the tutorial source files so everything's the same: The instructor says to "double-click on the layer in the timeline", but when I do that nothing happens.

I also tried right-clicking on the layer, but the "open layer" option is grayed out.

Finally, I switched to the "All Panels" workspace, select the Layer Panel, but it's gray and empty and doesn't allow me to choose a layer or add a new layer view.

I'm new to After Effects but experienced with CS5 - I just can't figure out what's wrong

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Figured it out- Apparently shape layers can't be opened in the Layer Panel. That includes Illustrator footage layers with "Continuous Rasterization" turned on. If you turn Continuous rasterization off, it *will* open in the Layer Panel.